# Payout with PayPal using card details?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, paypal, paypal-sandbox, payout

Im using paypal api for my payment integration , in my application there is flow for payout to customers where i can able to payout to the customers paypal account but how can i payout to customer credit/debit card

Answer (score 2):

With regular PayPal APIs, only sending money to a PayPal account or email address is supported.

You might be interested in [Hyperwallet](https://www.hyperwallet.com/resources/developers-product-documentation/debit-card-as-a-transfer-method/), a PayPal service.